Ubuntu 24 LTS with Entra ID login
The release document for Ubuntu 24 LTS mentioned better integration with Azure AD (now Entra ID). So we're trying to set it up using "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-linux", but getting unsupported linux version (OS: ubuntu v24.04 x86_64) error. Anyone experienced something similar and workaround?
Just in case, we're interested in SSH login using EntraID. And we're trying to install packages aadsshlogin and aadsshlogin-selinux extensions to the VM per Microsoft Document.

Your problem is not with Ubuntu it is with Microsoft. They have not updated their software to work with Ubuntu 24.04.
